# GCM on iOS error when generating token: (com.google.iid error 7.)

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an app using push notification with **GCM (Google Cloud Messaging)** services. 
The thing is: sometimes when generating a token, it shows this error:

GCM failed with error:

> The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (com.google.iid error 7.)

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: In the CGM documentation it says that error code 7 is for unknown errors. You have to give us more information. We don't know what is going on if you just says you get error code 7.

Comment: Have you tried to generate an APNS certificate and use it to make a plist file? Also, have you tried the GCM example application? You can see [this example](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/start) for detail.

Comment: I checked out the GCM documentation as well as the exemple application.  And I also used a APNS certificate to generate the plist file. My application is generating the token and sending it when the user logs in on the app. So far I'm doing some testing to understand more the problem and give u some more info. But for now, this is as much as I have.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but only the first time I run the app. If I try to run it again, I'm able to get the notifications. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I actually did not do anything on the app and it turned out to work properly after some time.