# GCM IOS error - Registration to GCM failed with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.iid error 7.)

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

I'm getting this error only the first time the app is opened

```
Registration to GCM failed with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.iid error 7.)
```

If I try to run the app again, Im able to register and get a token and receive the push messages.

I already tried the solution on [unable to register (com.google.iid error 1005.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30737406/unable-to-register-com-google-iid-error-1005)

But still having the problem.

Any idea of how can I fix that?

Thanks

EDIT:
The same error is happening on the Quickstart sample app

[image]

This is the xcode log from Quickstart sample app

```
2015-10-14 15:40:51.722 GcmExampleSwift[680:149607] Successfully configured [CloudMessaging].
2015-10-14 15:40:51.723 GcmExampleSwift[680:149607] Failed to configure [].
2015-10-14 15:40:51.723 GcmExampleSwift[680:149607] Subspecs not present, so not configured [Analytics, AdMob, SignIn, AppInvite, Maps].
2015-10-14 15:40:51.723 GcmExampleSwift[680:149607] Subspecs expected to be present [CloudMessaging, Measurement].
2015-10-14 15:40:51.829: GCM | MCS Registration is not ready with auth credentials
Connected to GCM
Registration to GCM failed with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.iid error 7.)
Could not connect to GCM: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.gcm error 2001.)
```

Comment: Does the issue occur with the [quickstart sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/ios/gcm)?

Comment: yes, it does happens in the quickstart sample app, same error message "Registration to GCM failed with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.iid error 7.)"

Comment: Can you post your more log messages from your XCode, (ex, the log starting from when your app is launch)

Comment: I added the xcode log from Quickstart Sample App

Comment: Im not the only one having this problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32483127/gcm-on-ios-error-when-generating-token-com-google-iid-error-7

Answer (score 0):

I think you got this issue because the time on my phone was set in the future, once the time was set correctly the problem was resolved.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing `kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption` with a value of `YES` for sandbox or `NO` for *production* environment as mentioned in the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client#obtain_a_registration_token).